# Dynamic number of columns in select clause in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, select, dynamic, user-defined-functions

I have the need to dynamically fetch column values from a table.

Say I have a table having columns:

```
Name,
Date,
Col1,
Col2,
Col3,
...
col10
```

Now, depending on some condition I want to fetch different columns from col1 to col10 from above table keeping Name, date columns always in select clause. e.g. is as below.

```
columns in output:  (1) Name (2) date (3) col1 + col2 + col3  (4) col4 + col5
```

i.e. number of columns and columns itself (colN) both varies.

How can I achieve that? Also, fixed columns are specified directly in select clause like.

```
select Name, Date  ... from Table1
```

But, to get remaining column values for each row I am using table-valued function. So, in that function how can I get value? I can make a dynamic SQL string but cannot execute it in a function, so this is the limitation I am facing.

Comment: to achieve this, you will definitely required to use `dynamic query` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally achieved this by generating a dynamic query string then executing it.

To generate dynamic string I first take the fixed columns using "with" and then with each row running function. Something as below.

```
set @str = ';with fn as (select ... fixed-columns from table) select x.*'

while (condition)
begin
   set @cols = @cols + function_to_generate_dynamic_columns(@params)
   set @i=@i+1
end

set @str = @str + @cols + ' from fn x '

EXECUTE(@str)
```