# Column divided into sub columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I have created a table like this with some data.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #EmployeeDetail
CREATE TABLE #EmployeeDetail(Name nvarchar(50),Department nvarchar(50),IsActive INT)
INSERT INTO #EmployeeDetail(Name,Department,IsActive)
VALUES ( 'John','Account', 1 ), ( 'Harry', 'Store', 0), ( 'Smile', 'HR', 1);
```

The output of the query is

| Name | Department | IsActive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Account | 1 |
| Harry | Store | 0 |
| Smile | HR | 1 |

Then I did pivoting where the row becomes column by using this query

```
DECLARE 
    @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
    @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

 

    
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #EmployeeDetail
CREATE TABLE #EmployeeDetail(Name nvarchar(50),Department nvarchar(50),IsActive INT)
INSERT INTO #EmployeeDetail(Name,Department,IsActive)
VALUES ( 'John','Account', 1 ), ( 'Harry', 'Store', 0), ( 'Smile', 'HR', 1);

 

SELECT 
    @columns+=QUOTENAME(Department) + ','
FROM    #EmployeeDetail;

 

    SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

 

    DECLARE @GrandTotalCol    NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @GrandTotalCol = COALESCE (@GrandTotalCol + 'ISNULL ([' + 
CAST (Department AS VARCHAR) +'],0) + ', 'ISNULL([' + CAST(Department AS VARCHAR)+ '],0) + ')
FROM     #EmployeeDetail
  GROUP BY Department
  ORDER BY Department;
 SET @GrandTotalCol = LEFT (@GrandTotalCol, LEN (@GrandTotalCol)-1);
SET @sql ='
SELECT *, (' + @GrandTotalCol + ') 
AS [Grand Total] INTO  #temp_MatchesTotal FROM   
(
    SELECT 
        Name, 
        Department
        
    FROM #EmployeeDetail
) t 
PIVOT(
  COUNT(Department) 
    FOR Department IN ('+ @columns +')
)

 

 AS pivot_table
 SELECT * FROM  #temp_MatchesTotal
  DROP TABLE  #temp_MatchesTotal
 
 ;';

 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

which gives the output like this:

| Name | Account | Store | HR | Grand Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Harry | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Smile | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Now it seems to be pretty well until this, but now i want to extract a table in a report like this:
[image]

Is there any way to achieve these type of thing through query ? So that i could easily map the extracted data into the report. Here the pivoted column is also filtered according to IsActive column in the table #EmployeeDetail.

Comment: You can't have multiple headers layer in a SQL query, no. This is something for your reporting/presentation layer. I would suggest you should do the (dynamic) pivoting in there. Perhaps use a matrix in SSRS.

Comment: @Larnu how can i extract the data through query so that these data can be easily mapped in those reports with those tables?

Comment: Just select all your data out and use whatever pivoting tools your reporting software uses. SQL is not made for that kind of pivoting

Answer (score 0):

You can get something similar to the desired result. I used `CASE` statements to transpose the result:

You will need two `CASE` statement for each department (one for IsActive and another for IsNotActive).

```
SELECT 
      Name,
      SUM(CASE WHEN (Department = 'Account' AND IsActive = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AccountIsActive,
      SUM(CASE WHEN (Department = 'Account' AND IsActive = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AccountIsNotActive,
      
      SUM(CASE WHEN (Department = 'Store' AND IsActive = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StoreIsActive,
      SUM(CASE WHEN (Department = 'Store' AND IsActive = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StoreIsNotActive,
      
      SUM(CASE WHEN (Department = 'HR' AND IsActive = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HRIsActive,
      SUM(CASE WHEN (Department = 'HR' AND IsActive = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HRIsNotActive,
      
      COUNT(IsActive) AS GrandTotal
      
FROM #EmployeeDetail
GROUP BY Name;
```

Output:

| Name | AccountIsActive | AccountIsNotActive | StoreIsActive | StoreIsNotActive | HRIsActive | HRIsNotActive | GrandTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Harry | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| John | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Smile | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

**Dynamic query**

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(query_piece, '')

FROM (

    (SELECT 'SELECT Name,' AS query_piece)

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT 
        CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN Department = ''', Department, ''' AND IsActive = ', IsActive,
            ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ', Department, '_', CASE WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN 'IsActive' ELSE 'IsNotActive' END, ',')
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Department FROM #EmployeeDetail) AS sqD
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT IsActive FROM #EmployeeDetail) AS sqIA)

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT 'COUNT(IsActive) AS GrandTotal
         FROM #EmployeeDetail
         GROUP BY Name;')) AS dynamic_query;
```

Dynamic query output is your requested query:

```
SELECT Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Department = 'Account' AND IsActive = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Account_IsNotActive,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Department = 'HR' AND IsActive = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HR_IsNotActive,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Department = 'Store' AND IsActive = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Store_IsNotActive,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Department = 'Account' AND IsActive = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Account_IsActive,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Department = 'HR' AND IsActive = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HR_IsActive,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Department = 'Store' AND IsActive = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Store_IsActive,
    COUNT(IsActive) AS GrandTotal
FROM #EmployeeDetail
GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: This is the static approach but  the fields in department might not be same every time . So need dynamic approach.

Comment: You can check this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67167807/15424227) to make a dynamic query, or adapt your original query using this approach.